# How to display validation error inside of an input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In my rails app I'm using **simple_form**. I need to get the error messages in the input field instead of it being displayed on the side, like the image shown below.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to move the error field into the area of the input field.

**example.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <%= f.text_field :email, class: "email" %>
  <span class="error">
</div>
```

**example.css**

```
.row .error {
   margin: -20px;
}
```

example: http://codepen.io/phelpsiv/pen/ZOaomq